# Event Listeners applied to several divs elements on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript to display a modal popup when a div element is clicked.  This works great for the first div element (id "myCheck") but I would like to extend this to display the modal popup when other div elements with a similar id (myCheck2, myCheck3 etc) are clicked.

I have tried a few things such as:

1. document.querySelectorAll()
2. Adding Click Event Listeners In A Loop

Many thanks

```
<div id="myCheck" name="myCheckName" class="board_order">Some text</div>
<div id="myCheck2" name="myCheckName" class="board_order">Some text</div>
```

```
var id = document.getElementById("myCheck");
id.addEventListener("click", displayModal);

function displayModal() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Some CSS

```
/* The Modal (background) */
  .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 150px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 75%;
  }

  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: Combine approaches 1 and 2 and post the resulting code.

Comment: _"I have tried a few things..."_ - Those things sound like a viable solution. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take advantage of the event delegation (Basically you attach the click event listener in the common parent)

```
<div class="parent">
 <div data-value="1">div 1</div>
 <div data-value="2">div 2</div>
</div>

document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', handleAction);

function handleAction(ev) {
 console.log(ev.target.dataset.value);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Using event delegation like this has achieved exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank You very much